# What is an .env (or dotenv) file exactly?

Tags: dotenv

There's a lot of programs out there that can utilize `.env` files. Most of them support the basic bash-syntax, others support more advanced things like templating within the `.env` files. The way you're supposed to use `.env` files varies a lot as well. Often in this context, you'll year from the 12-factor-app which states that you should [export (some) configuration as environment variables](https://12factor.net/config), that apparently lead to two use cases:

- [Some](https://pypi.org/project/dotenv-cli/) `dotenv` **programs** do just that: you prefix your command on the shell with `dotenv` and the variables in the dotenv file will magically be available in you process.
- [Others](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) however provide **libraries** that actually read `.env` files from within your code -- a very different approach since your code is suddenly interpreting `.env` files directly and does not "see" the environment variables anymore.

Since there's so many different interpretations of usage, use-cases and syntax, is there a proper definition of `.env` files or some commonly accepted standard? If not, at least some historical references?

Answer (score 11):

It appears that `.env` files lack a complete definition.

This reference:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local

Links here:

http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html

Which leads here:

https://ddollar.github.io/foreman/

Which contains this:

```
ENVIRONMENT
    If a .env file exists in the current directory, the default
    environment will be read from it. This file should contain key/value
    pairs, separated by =, with one key/value pair per line.

        FOO=bar
        BAZ=qux
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this link https://hexdocs.pm/dotenvy/0.2.0/dotenv-file-format.html

The escape rules worked for loading GitHub CLI secret and variable values which contained quotes (JSON).

Beyond that, I can't vouch for its accuracy, completeness, or if any given .env consumer will have the same implementation.

YMMV

***EDIT***

Apparently the hexdocs implementation is based on this one: https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

so now there are two of them.