# Github Actions logs says .env: permission denied, but I don't use this file

Tags: git, docker, github, github-actions

I have a GitHub repository where I build, publish and deploy an application via Docker Compose, using GitHub Actions.
When doing `docker compose up -d`, the workflow throws the error

> stat /path/to/build/.env: permission denied

Although I do not use this file.

Given the workflow file *.github/workflows/action.yml*:

```yaml
on: [push]

jobs:
  compose_up:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      ## This step is just here to reproduce the problematic behaviour
      - run: install -m 000 /dev/null .env
      - run: docker compose up -d
```

And a minimal *compose.yml* containing:

```yaml
services:
  demo:
    image: alpine
```

I would expect `docker compose up -d` to create the containers without any error, but the containers are not created.

---

Here are some trials and the their corresponding errors

```yaml
env_file:
     - /dev/null
```

> error: stat /path/to/file/.env: permission denied

```bash
docker compose --env-file /dev/null -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

> error: stat /path/to/file/docker-compose.yml: permission denied

```bash
docker compose --env-file /dev/null up
```

> error: no configuration file provided: not found

```bash
COMPOSE_ENV_FILES=/dev/null docker compose up
```

> error: stat /path/to/file/.env: permission denied

Comment: Are you sure you do have access to anything on this box/container? What does `- run: ls -la .env && ls -la docker-compose.yml && whoami` gives you?

Comment: .env doesn't exist, but it says permission denied, after bypassing .env, this error gone, but again it says docker-compose.yml permission denied and it exist with permission root:root

I am using the self-hosted runner which runs as github:github ownership and i execute docker compose with webshop user, docker-compose.yml files created with envsubst during pipeline with user root:root but on next step when i run the docker compose with webshop user it says permission denied, and the webshop user is the member of github group. The same steps works for other branch on this repo fine

Comment: the issue seems to be not just .env because now it is bypassed and facing issue with docker-compose.yml permission denied, some how the webshop user running docker command unable to access docker-compose.yml root:root where as same works in case of other branch

Answer (score 1):

The fact that Docker Compose does load a `.env` file in the same folder as the compose file is [a default behaviour](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#compose-file) of the command.

I can totally see the need to bypass that, though, as the [*dotenv* files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68267862/what-is-an-env-or-dotenv-file-exactly) have become such a common standard in most languages, you might not want the *.env* file at the root of the project to be used by Docker.

There is actually [an open request on their issue tracker](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6741) to allow skipping it.

As raised on this feature request by [@jelhan](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6741#issuecomment-596205657), one trick is to override the environment file with the `--env-file` flag and pass it `/dev/null`:

```bash
docker compose --env-file /dev/null up
```

<sup>*Source: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6741#issuecomment-596205657*</sup>

So, in your workflow:

```yaml
- run: docker compose --env-file /dev/null up
```

One other way is to use the [`COMPOSE_ENV_FILES`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars/#compose_env_files) variable, either in your command line, shell session or CI/CD pipeline.

E.g.:

```yaml
- run: COMPOSE_ENV_FILES=/dev/null docker compose up
```

Or, globally defined in your workflow, so at the top level of your worflow YAML:

```yaml
env:
  COMPOSE_ENV_FILES: /dev/null

on: [push]

jobs:
  compose_up:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - run: install -m 000 /dev/null .env
      - run: docker compose up -d
```

Comment: Hi @β.εηοιτ.βε, thanks for your quick response, i have updated my question with results, some how, still it is not working